# Whitelist admin section of Kentico

Tags: asp.net, web-config, ip, kentico, whitelist

I don't like the world seeing the admin interface of my Kentico site.  Kentico allows you to create a new folder for admin pages but the existing folder is still there and its pages still accessible.  I want to whitelist the admin folder by IP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following section to your web.config.  This enables an IP whitelist for the admin folder. More details [here](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/ipsecurity?showTreeNavigation=true).

```
  <location path="Admin">
    <system.webServer>
      <security>        
        <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false" denyAction="NotFound">
          <clear />
          <add allowed="true" subnetMask="255.255.255.255" ipAddress="987.654.321.012" /> <!-- add your IP here -->
        </ipSecurity>
      </security>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
```

Comment: Will this lockout the admin for the general public? i'm looking at doing something like this.

Comment: it will allow anyone within that subnet and IP address or address range to access the /admin path of the site everyone else will be denied.